# python openweather package dont work

Tags: python, python-2.7, openweathermap

hello I try to follow this [manual](https://pypi.org/project/openweather/0.11/) to take python open weather api

here the example manula code :

```
import openweather
from datetime import datetime

# create client
ow = openweather.OpenWeather()

# find weather stations near me
stations = ow.find_stations_near(
    7.0,  # longitude
    50.0, # latitude
    100   # kilometer radius
)

# iterate results
for station in stations:
    print station
```

but that don't work I take this error message :

```
OpenWeather.do_request(): No connection. (1. attempt)
OpenWeather.do_request(): No connection. (2. attempt)
OpenWeather.do_request(): No connection. (3. attempt)
```

any idea why ?

Comment: The link you've provided is incorrect.

Comment: @Q.Holness I fix it thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to append a valid API key to the 'create client' request. what this package does is parse your input into a JSON request and return so it needs to have the API key when you create a client in order to append it to the URL it sends to openweathermap.

```
import openweather
from datetime import datetime

# create client
ow = openweather.OpenWeather('3f14d26ebe5502a831e98067ae851b99')

# find weather stations near me
stations = ow.find_stations_near(
    7.0,  # longitude
    50.0, # latitude
    100   # kilometer radius
)

# iterate results
for station in stations:
    print station
```

Comment: now I take this error : `Requesting http://openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/station?lat=50.0&lon=7.0&radius=20
OpenWeather.do_request(): No connection. (1. attempt)` and if I open this url tell me `{
"cod": 401,
"message": "Invalid API key. Please see http://openweathermap.org/faq#error401 for more info."
}` but why ? I have correct key and I try with yours key and again some error

Comment: openweather latest version is last updated on May 14, 2014, and starting from 9 October 2015 OpenWeatherMap API requires a valid APPID for access. The package is probably out of date. You might want to checkout their url based API access as it is very easy to recreate that package's functionality using a few functions.

Comment: I need valid kay for 2014 or better how to take json API for per weather station in my country ?is easy way?can I contact you via email ?thank for help

Comment: @mar The package you're using is out of date, you can check it on it's github page. If you want to stick with python you should check the pyowm package